# Значение слов "санкции" и "санкционированный"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Почему слово "санкции" означает запрет, а слово "санкционированный" — разрешение? Как так вышло, если они оба произошли от одного латинского слова?

Comment: Ответы нужно давать в ответах.

Comment: Конечно, но это вопрос.

Comment: Misha20062006, этот комментарий относится не к вашему вопросу, а к удаленным ответам из комментариев :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существительное "санкция" многозначно.

**САНКЦИЯ**, -и; *ж.* [от лат. sanctio (sanctionis) — нерушимый закон, строжайшее постановление] *Юрид.*
**1. Утверждение чего-л. высшей инстанцией, разрешение.** *Получить санкцию на арест. Дать санкцию на выпуск номера в печать. Задержан с санкции прокурора.*
**2.** Мера, применяемая государством к правонарушителю. *Санкции уголовного суда за взяточничество. Уголовные, административные санкции.*
**3.** Мера, принимаемая против стороны, нарушившей соглашение, договор. *Применение экономических санкций против воюющей стороны. Использование политических санкций по отношению к государству-агрессору.*

[**Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов**](https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Причастие **"санкционированный"** соотносится с существительным **"санкция"** в первом значении.

**САНКЦИОНИРОВАТЬ**, рую, руешь; анный; *сов*. и *несов., что* (*книжн.*). Дать (давать) санкцию **(в 1 *знач.*)** чему-н. *С. чьё-н. решение.*

[**Толковый словарь С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой**](https://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, спасибо!